# Initialize const members using complex function in C++ class

Tags: c++, class, initialization-list

I have a program that works with 3d grids. This grid has its own class object Grid that looks like this (simplified version):

```
class Grid
{
  public:
    Grid() { readDataFromInputFile(); }
  private:
    void readDataFromInputFile() {...} // this function reads the values for i, j, k from disk
    int i; int j; int k;
};
```

What I would like to do now, is to be able to set the variables i, j and k as const int, to avoid messing them accidentally up in the other functions. I can however not easily set them in a member initializer list, because they have to be read from file. I have been browsing through the existing discussions but I couldn't find an accurate discussion on this problem.

Is there a solution to be able to set them as const, and still be able to use a complex function to retrieve the data? In my real application, there are of course much more variables to be read, that are not allowed to change after initialization.

Comment: Oops, readDataFromInput is also a member function, I only put it to make clear that I use a complex function including IO that reads a number of variables from an .ini file from disk.

Comment: I have edited the post, to make it more clear.

Comment: Looks like I understood correctly what you meant even if the code didn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: One option is to make the variables be `i_`, `j_`, `k_` or other unlikely names, and have class members `int const &i` which you bind to `i_` in the constructor (this can be done before `i_` has had its value assigned)

Comment: "Is there a solution to be able to set them as const...?" - No, not with this design. `const` means they *must* be initialized prior to any usage or *access to usage*, including the constructor body, invoking any non-static member function etc. Like reference members (const or not), they *must* appear in the field initializer list of the constructor(s). There is no escaping that. That is simply how the language works. Manu's assessment is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't break the One Responsibility Principle: A `Grid` should not be responsible of loading itself from a file, this is a responsibility of another component (For example a simple loading function):

```
class Grid
{
public:
    Grid( int ii , int jj , int kk ) : i{ ii } , j{ jj } , k{ kk }
private:
    const int i , j , k;
};

Grid loadGrid( constd std::string& filename )
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I don't want to read the entire Grid class from memory, only a few of its data members.

Comment: @Chiel this doesn't solve your problem directly because a) You provided a simplified view of your class (Which is ok and what you should do always when asking here), and b) this answer provides an explanation about why your design is wrong and what is the proper way to handle this situation. Making the solution properly working is your job :)

Comment: @Chiel Then don't read the entire grid class. The point is to decouple the responsibilities.

Comment: But how do you picture it then? loadGrid returns a Grid object that is being filled with all the data that has been read from disk and I instead of calling Grid grid, I call Grid grid = loadGrid("banana")?

Comment: @Chiel exactly. You have got it well

Comment: One more question about your "One Responsibility Principle". Why should an object not be responsible for loading itself? In my view in order to make objects independent, they should take care of themselves in OOP. Which part of the paradigm do I not understand?

Comment: @Chiel what you don't understand is the role of objects: An object is designed to take care of something. That could be a file, a string, etc. Each class is designed (should be designed) to manage only one thing, if you need to manage multiple things use aggregation. In your case, the mesh manages a, well, a mesh; and the responsability of loading a mesh should not be part of its contract. It is only a mesh, after all. If you want to load meshes, you have to create other class in charge of loading meshes.

Comment: But according to which criteria do you decide what comes in an own object, and what is functionality of the object itself? What I have now, is that on a grid, you can create a variable, that has its own class Field. I, however, have kept the number of classes small, where I have one for each entity (Grid, Field, PhysicalOperator). In your philosophy (which I am trying to understand, not to criticize), I would end up with an enormous amount of objects.

Comment: @Chiel its only a good design principle to avoid coupling and scalability problems in the future. But you should decide at what level you want to apply that rule, to balance class bloating vs coupling. Also remember that C++ is not OOP, is multiparadigm. What I have given you is the pure OOP point of view (i.e. ala Java), but in the case of C++ responsability decoupling does not have to end on more classes.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve setting const memebers with complex behavioour is to initialize them using a functoin. In your case if I understand correctly, these members are initialized using one function call, so it's better if that function just return the members's value so that you can set the const memebers. 
Something that should look like this:

```
class Grid
{
  public:
    Grid() : data( readFromInputFile() ) {  }
  private:
    struct Data{
    int i; int j; int k;
    };
    const Data data;
};
```

This simple alternative should solve your problem. The only thing to change is the way you access the data, data.i instead of i. Once data is initialized (readFromInputFile() returning a Data too), it can't be changed.

If you need readFromInputFile() to not be a member or static member function, then move the definition of Data outside of the class or make it public.

Comment: A variation of this is to make `Data` actually be a base class of `Grid` ; then you can use `i` instead of `data.i` when referring to it

Comment: @MattMcNabb A private base yes, however that's only necessary if that base is reused somewhere else, otherwise the syntax cost is so cheap that it's not necessary to do so.

Comment: But this makes working with the class considerably less pleasant. The class contains a large number of manipulation functions that loop over i, j and k, and reading from array values[i + a*j + b*k], which become highly unreadable.

Comment: If `readFromInputFile` is a non-static member function of `Grid` you're invoking said-member before the object is actually constructed. (the constructor body hasn't even been entered, much less finished). I can certainly see `static` or non-member-outright working, with the function friended to the class to access the private type.

Comment: Yes, that's basically a hack based on the first version of the question. Now that it's clarified, if it is possible ot initialize i,j and k separately, the validated answer is far better. Use this hack only if there is no way to initialize the data separately and you can't change the architecture. Otherwise, just reorganizing things around immutable data will work far better.